# Click Handling from GridView in Java on Android

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am beginner to both Java and Android development, I am sure that I am doing this wrong; it’s just the way I've figured it out so far. That said, I have an app that will show something like a golf scorecard. There is a section (major row) for each of 4 players. Each player row comprises 3 sub-rows; one for Par (18 values in the row), one for Hole Handicap (18 values), one for  Score (18 values). I want the user to click on a major row and have another activity appear based on the player named in the clicked row.

So, I created an XML layout with a single ListView. I created an XML layout for the page header with a GridView defining 12 columns each with a TextView for column headers, and I created an XML layout for the major row with a GridView comprising TextViews for 54 items (3 sub-rows of 18 items). I also added an onClick listener to the GridLayout declaration in the row def XML. Throw in a custom arrayAdapter to handle the 4 players and I get my scorecard on the screen.

Everything displays okay, and when I click a major row, I get to a debug breakpoint in the clickListener and I can fire off an Intent to kick off the activity showing player detail. But, I don’t know  how to determine which player (major row) was clicked.

```
String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

in the click handler crashes the app, I suppose because the clickListener was established on a GridLayout or some such thing.

So, what’s wrong with the setup and how can I get what I need to go forward?

Thanks

Here is relevant code. Sorry if it's a lot...

activity_display_scorecard.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"> 

     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is activity_sisplay_scorecard_row.xml (I edited out columns 4-12)

```
    <GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:useDefaultMargins="true"
    android:alignmentMode="alignBounds"
    android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:columnCount="12" 
    android:id="@+id/SCRow"
    android:onClick="displayScore"
    >
    <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />
    <TextView
            android:text="Par"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Par_Hole_1"
            android:text="V_1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
<!-- A bunch more for this row -->
    <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />
    <TextView
            android:text="HCP"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HCP_Hole_1"
            android:text="V_1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
<!-- A bunch more for this row -->
    <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="Name"
            android:id="@+id/Row_Name"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="Bet"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Bet_Hole_1"
            android:text="B1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

    <!-- A bunch more for this row -->
    <TextView
            android:text=""
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            />

    <TextView
            android:text="Score"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            />


    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Score_Hole_1"
            android:text="V_1"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

<!-- A bunch more for this row -->

</GridLayout>
```

and here is the activity DisplayScorecard

```
public class DisplayScorecard extends Activity {
private ListView listView1;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_scorecard);


    CardRow scoreCard_data[] = new CardRow[]
    {
        new CardRow(0),
        new CardRow(1),
        new CardRow(2),
        new CardRow(3)
    };

    CardRowAdapter adapter = new CardRowAdapter(this, 
            R.layout.activity_display_scorecard_row, scoreCard_data);


    listView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    View header = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_display_scorecard_header, null);
    listView1.addHeaderView(header);

    listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

  }

/** Called when the user Selects a scorecard row */
public void displayScore(View view) {
    String item = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ABC" + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayScore.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}    


}
```

Comment: You should post the relevant part of code instead of describing it and add the logcat =)

Comment: it crashes because your view is not initialized an you are probably getting `NullPointerException`

Comment: Raghunandan, not sure what you mean.